# Pass Dynamic Values from one function to another function in class

Tags: php

Hi all i have a function in a class which will print all the variable pass for this function

**Class Code :**

```
<?php
 class MyPrintClass {
   public function printVaraible() {
     var_dump(func_get_args())
   }
 }

 $printVar = new MyPrintClass;
?>
```

if i use like below its correctly working and printing all the values pass.

```
$print->printVaraible('value1','Value2',20);
```

The output i got for above cmd

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'value1' (length=6)
  1 => string 'value2' (length=6)
  2 => string 'value3' (length=6)
```

if i use like blow its showing as a single array.. i want the value seperated.. how its possible ?

```
function getVal(){
  global $printVar;
  $print->printVaraible(func_get_args());
}
```

I need to pass the value like below

```
getVal('value1','Value2',20);
```

and i need the output as

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'value1' (length=6)
  1 => string 'value2' (length=6)
  2 => string 'value3' (length=6)
```

Currently i get **NULL** as the output

**Updated Question Based On the Answer Given By** deceze
** I Also had a small change in my code**
**Class Code :**

```
<?php
  class MyPrintClass {
    public function printVaraible($tag,$value) {
      echo $tag.' == '.$value;
      var_dump(func_get_args());
    }
  }

  $printVar = new MyPrintClass;
?>
```

**Converted Class To Function By**

```
<?php
function getVal($tag,$value) {
 global $printVar;
 call_user_func_array([$printVar, 'printVariable'], $tag,$value,func_get_args());
}
```

?>

**If i try to use it as below i get error**

```
<?php getVal('first','second','third,'fourth'); ?>
```

**`Warning: call_user_func_array() expects exactly 2 parameters, 4 given`**

Comment: You're using `global $printVar` but are then refer to `$print`...!?

Comment: @deceze its typing mistake but i got the output frm your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
call_user_func_array([$print, 'printVariable'], func_get_args());
```

This calls the function with separate parameters from an array. I'd question the usefulness of this though, since you'll just end up with an array from `func_get_args` anyway. Why not pass arrays around in the first place?

Comment: i used this but i get return null as the value

Comment: when i call the function in my class i get null as return value pls check my updated question

Answer (score 1):

Your getting null in the return because you never return anything, from the functions above.

if you want to call a class method I suggest you look into Refection or you can also do

```
$a = 'printVaraible';

$class->$a(1,3); //
```

besides using call_user_func_array, I would also suggest looking into closures (php > 5.3 ), which will let you write them this way.

```
$a = function foo(){ echo 'foo'};
$a();
```

Last thing I would generally avoid using global, as it obscures in your code where the values come from.  It is always better to inject values into the function scope and not mix that with the global, imaging hunting that global down in a large project, I just avoid them at all cost and forget they exist.

Comment: thanks for your answer as you told to add `return in function`. its working